# rendering front-end of survey into an MVC app

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

Lately I have been watching Pluralsight intro videos on MVC 3. I have never worked with the Model View Control approach before, but I'm starting to understand how these 3 crucial parts of an app are separated.

I created a front-end prototype of a survey I would like to implement into a View of my MVC web app. The survey is in HTML, CSS, using jQuery to deliver content changes depending on the type of evaluation (6-11 questions), and jQuery UI for a couple slider ratings.

I noticed through tutorials that you can use an HTML form and helpers that allow the user to edit content, but my prototype already allows the users to rate via radio buttons, comment text boxes, and sliders. Would I need to change any of my existing code if I just want to store this employee data to the Model, and depending on what survey's the employee has completed through the Controller, disable drop down fields?

Also, would I store the current employee data on submit of survey through an HttpPost in the Controller to the Model?

My apologies if my questions seem rather vague. Could someone point me in the right direction to a resource or documentation similar to my needs above? The Pluralsight videos are taking me in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form helpers you mentioned are optional. You could use a static HTML page in an MVC app with no issues, but it'll mean some extra work.

All the helpers are doing is rendering HTML for you to save you the trouble of handcoding it.

Your form should have a `action` attribute, and you can point that at an MVC controller URL. The data will arrive in your controller in the request, and you can pull the values out by hand. There are a number of ways to do this, including pulling the values out by key:

```
public ActionResult HelloWorld()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Hello World!";
    return View();
}
```

That would retrieve the value of a form input with a `name="Message"` attribute.

The best way to collect these values, though, is to allow ASP.NET MVC to map them to a .NET object for you. Read up on model binding to see how that works.

If you like books, I highly recommend [Wrox Professional ASP.NET MVC3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118076583). It's very approachable and will cut your learning curve drastically. Good stuff.

Comment: Doesn't HTML helpers "Set" data from objects in a controller or model? This wouldn't make any sense if I was just trying to "Get" data from user input.

Are there any examples of using HTML Helpers that would be beneficial for creating, let's say, 3 radio button questions. I know you can use HTML.beginform to render a form, but what I'm just confused on how you render what I created statically in this form through C#.

Comment: HTML helpers are pretty flexible, and you can write your own, so you might see some that prepopulate form fields with existing data. That doesn't seem like it applies in your case, though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick example. I'll follow up on model binding in Pluralsight.

Comment: A lot of MVC features like HTML helpers are designed to let you quickly render HTML on the server side with less code. They are less useful if you plan to do a lot of client side work with Backbone or jQuery. I don't think there's much benefit to using them for your three radio button scenario. It would make it easier to repopulate them in a scenario where some server-side validation fails and you want to ask the user to change what they entered.